# Getting touch event on Windows Phone 8 even when stopping or reversing a scroll fling

Tags: windows-phone-8

None of my screen-touch events (ManipulationStarted, MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseMove, Tap etc.) are fired when stopping or reversing a scroll fling on a ScrollViewer. How do I capture a screen-touch event even when this happens?

These events are fired OK after the ScrollViewer has completely stopped flinging, just not when stopping or reversing an existing fling.

EDIT: I need to get the actual element that was touched.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to make use of `FrameReported` event, in which you can read gesture from  [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx). Simple example can look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = (GestureType)1023; // read all gestures
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        float Xposition = gesture.Position.X;
        float Yposition = gesture.Position.Y;
    }
}
```

Depending on your purpose you can enable some gestures and read various properties from them.

Comment: I get the touch event but this doesn't tell me which item was touched - how do I query the relevant top, bottom, left and right of any `UIElement` (e.g. `Image`) in my scrolling layout so that I can use the `Xposition` and `Yposition` numbers in your example to determine of the `UIElement` was touched? I've edited the question. If there is no way, then do you suggest any other way to get the touched item under these circumstances?

Comment: @Navigateur Yes - this won't give infotmation about UIElement. If you want to check single element you can try to check that element's position `GeneralTransform myTransform = App.Current.RootVisual.TransformToVisual(UIElement); Point myPoint = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));`. But it is a hard workaround. But why not to use Tap event of UIElement?

Comment: Because the Tap event never fires under the conditions described. The Tap event should fire upon releasing the screen upon performing an ordinary tap (without any drag) during any existing fling animation, but it doesn't, and is either a bad design decision by Microsoft or an accidental bug.

Comment: @Navigateur In this case the method won't help you much. And I must say I'm out of ideas.